# When and where the concept `reference` was introduced

Tags: reference, history

This might be frivolous, thus googles are not helpful.

C++, python ... utilize reference as a syntactic sugar to substitute pointer,

I tried to look up the original meaning the concept reference to get an deeper understanding of its usage in various language.

When and from which language the concept `reference` was introduced, or on which paper it was coined?

Comment: According to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276366/are-questions-about-programming-history-in-scope-for-stack-overflow (and the history tag), this is off-topic (not saying that I agree with that, but that is what is written).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Back in C, people use the terms pointers and references interchangeably. The earliest known use of pointer is in 1964 in PL/I, according to [wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_(computer_programming)):

> Harold Lawson is credited with the 1964 invention of the pointer.[2] In 2000, Lawson was presented the Computer Pioneer Award by the IEEE “[f]or inventing the pointer variable and introducing this concept into PL/I, thus providing for the first time, the capability to flexibly treat linked lists in a general-purpose high level language”.[3]

References as a language feature in C++  has existed in C++ since before C++ standardization in 1998, so if you're a standard literalist it has been there since the initial standardization.

Early C++ history is a bit muddy because early versions of C++ wasn't even called C++. Back then C++ was essentially a language extension of C, and was called "C with classes", but reference first got into the language around early 1980s (according to [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B)). This was also around the time when C++ started forming its own identity as a separate language rather than just extension to C.

Python have neither pointers nor reference, so talking about reference when talking about Python is meaningless (note, there's a weakref module in the stdlib, but it's a totally different beast). However, people often have compared Python's variable-object name binding system to C++ reference system, as they share a lot of similarity; which is why Python is often called pass-by-reference language, however you should not take this terminology too seriously; reference is a foreign concept in Python, used only to make it easy for people used to another language to understand python's variable naming system.

Comment: amazing, thank you, I assume I was lost in python without the term reference. after all, C++ is an extension of C, while python is a shortcut of C, do you agree?